# Cruisecontrol- how to trigger build as soon as defect is moved to fixed or closed state

Tags: cruisecontrol

I was wondering if there is any way to trigger build as soon as defect is moved to fixed or closed state.
I am using ANT as build tool and AccuRev as version control tool

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on your defect tracker, more than your revision control. 
It might help to think about this the other way around - eg can you configure your defect tracker - (bugzilla/jira/clearddts etc) to trigger the build, perhaps by using the rest api.